# How can I change cardLayout card within child card?

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I have a parent class which is CardLayout. I also have two child classes(JPanel) that has textfields and buttons. What I want is when the user click a button on the first card the screen will change to the second screen. Here is the code

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private static LoginScreen login;
private static DatabaseSelection selector;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GUI frame = new GUI();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }); 
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public GUI() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    CardLayout card = new CardLayout();
    contentPane.setLayout(card);
    login = new LoginScreen();
    selector = new DatabaseSelection();
    contentPane.add(login, "1");
    contentPane.add(selector, "2");
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    card.show(contentPane, "1");
}
```

}

```
public class LoginScreen extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextField userName;
private JPasswordField passWord;
private JTextField port;
private JTextField host;
private JLabel hostLabel;
private JLabel portLabel;
private Connection con;

/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public LoginScreen() {
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    JLabel userNameLabel = new JLabel("Username: ");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_userNameLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_userNameLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_userNameLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_userNameLabel.gridx = 1;
    gbc_userNameLabel.gridy = 1;
    add(userNameLabel, gbc_userNameLabel);

    userName = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_userName = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_userName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_userName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_userName.gridx = 2;
    gbc_userName.gridy = 1;
    add(userName, gbc_userName);
    userName.setColumns(10);

    JLabel passWordLabel = new JLabel("Password: ");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_passWordLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_passWordLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_passWordLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_passWordLabel.gridx = 1;
    gbc_passWordLabel.gridy = 2;
    add(passWordLabel, gbc_passWordLabel);

    passWord = new JPasswordField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_passWord = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_passWord.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_passWord.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_passWord.gridx = 2;
    gbc_passWord.gridy = 2;
    add(passWord, gbc_passWord);

    JButton loginButon = new JButton("Login");
    loginButon.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_loginButon = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_loginButon.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbc_loginButon.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    gbc_loginButon.gridheight = 4;
    gbc_loginButon.gridx = 3;
    gbc_loginButon.gridy = 1;
    add(loginButon, gbc_loginButon);
    loginButon.addActionListener(this);

    hostLabel = new JLabel("Host: ");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_hostLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_hostLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_hostLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_hostLabel.gridx = 1;
    gbc_hostLabel.gridy = 3;
    add(hostLabel, gbc_hostLabel);

    host = new JTextField();
    host.setText("localhost");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_host = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_host.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_host.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_host.gridx = 2;
    gbc_host.gridy = 3;
    add(host, gbc_host);
    host.setColumns(10);

    portLabel = new JLabel("Port:");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_portLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_portLabel.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_portLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_portLabel.gridx = 1;
    gbc_portLabel.gridy = 4;
    add(portLabel, gbc_portLabel);

    port = new JTextField();
    port.setText("3306");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_port = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_port.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_port.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_port.gridx = 2;
    gbc_port.gridy = 4;
    add(port, gbc_port);
    port.setColumns(10);
    setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{userName, passWord, host, port, loginButon}));
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        ConnectionManager conMgr = new ConnectionManager(host.getText(), port.getText());
        char[] pass = passWord.getPassword();
        con = conMgr.getConnection(userName.getText(), new String(pass));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        System.out.println("Driver Error ...");
        //e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e1){
        System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have to use `card.show(..)` in an action

Comment: @nachokk But `LoginScreen` doesn't have direct access to the `CardLayout`... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, your shouldn't.  The current "card" should have no idea about the order of navigation, instead, it should be capable of either providing some kind of event notification (such as through an `ActionListener`) or tell some other manager that it needs to be switched for the next/previous/target "card"...

Having said that, you "could" extract the layout manager from the "card's" parent

```
LayoutManager layout = getParent().getLayout();
if (layout instanceof CardLayout) {
    CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout)layout;
    // switch panels...
}
```

But this will cause you no end of problems when the order of navigation changes, better to use some kind of "navigation" manager which can take care of it for your from a central controller.

As @nachokk has pointed out, this (controller) would represent a [Mediator Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/mediator-pattern.html)

Comment: +1 but when you mean `a central controller` you mean something like a mediator, where the different components in the layout are the colleagues?

Comment: @nachokk Oh well, if you want to get technical...yes...:P

Comment: i just made a question to understand your answer, was not sure what you mean

Comment: @nachokk I don't mind, didn't know the "pattern" name of the top of my head, so it's helpful ;)

Comment: I was planning to use the GUI class as the controller but i had some difficulties implementing it because of that I turned to this way. Then how can I convert the GUI class as the main controller. Also keep in my that this is my first swing experience that involves multiple JPanel classes.

Comment: Basically, start by creating an `interface` which describes what you want each element to be able to to do, for example, `next`, `previous` and maybe `goto` if you want to be really flexible.  Then define an implementation that wraps the main panel and the `CardLayout` (which I assume is set as the main panel's layout manager), so that when the only one calls one of the interface methods, you can interact with the `CardLayout` to make it happen.  The controller should know what the "current" page is so it can decide where it should move to based on what it is been asked to do.

Comment: Create an instance of this implementation and pass it to each panel that needs to be able to change...such as `LoginScreen` and `DatabaseSelection`...for example...